# If $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is a polynomial such that $f(1)=10, f(2)=20, f(3)=30$, find the value of $\frac{f(12)+f(-8)}{10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

**If $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is a polynomial such that $f(1)=10, f(2)=20, f(3)=30$, find the value of :-** $\frac{f(12)+f(-8)}{10}$

I tried to find the values of $a,b,c,d$ individually (which was a very long process).

Here's what I got

$a=\frac{-59}{12}$, $b=-54$.

The equation got too complicated before I could find the values of $c$ and $d$.

The answer is 1984.

This question is printed in an authorized book of Pearson Publication and was also asked in CMO 1984.

Comment: What is the $b$ you are talking about ? It isn't present in your polynomial ?

Comment: What is the context of the question ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ are unsolvable by itself, so your computation should be wrong somewhere, but $(f(12)+f(-8))/2$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: @Hw Chu Correct. Instead of finding a b c d individually I should have generalized the polynomial with respect to x.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $f(x)-10x$ have $1,2,3$ as its roots and have leading coefficient $1$, $f(x) = 10x + (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-t)$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(12) + f(-8) &= 10(12-8) + 11\cdot 10 \cdot 9\cdot(12-t) + (-11)(-10)(-9)(-8-t)\\
&= 40+11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot 20.
\end{aligned}
$$

Now you should be able to finish.

Comment: Hey, I've edited the question. The answer doesn't match your ans.

Comment: Take that as a hint. I don't think your answer contradicts what I got.

Comment: Thanks. NOW it is correct.

Comment: [+1] Clever answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the system
$$a+b+c+d+1=10$$
$$8a+4b+2c+d+16=20$$
$$27a+9b+3c+d+81=30$$

Comment: That's what I have got.

Comment: Have you solved the System?

Comment: No, I got these three equations but we can't solve the equation because there are three unknowns and we have only have 3 equations

Comment: The solution is given by $$ \left\{ a=-6-d/6,b=11+d,c=4-{\frac {11\,d}{6}},d=d \right\} $$